# noble - can it be split into morphemes?

Tags: meaning, grammar, etymology, linguistics, morphology

Can I split noble into nob + the suffix -le?

-le is found in other adjectives such as little, brittle, fickle

nob is found in noble, nobleman, nobleness, nobler, noblesse, noblest, nobly. But pretty much all of these contain 'noble', so maybe noble is the root morpheme?

Note: 'nob' on its own is apparently a slang word for a rich person. So it carries a similar meaning as a noun. Except it's British and informal?

Thanks!

Comment: You need to restore the question, undoing the changes you made that changed it from what it original was to just "Solved - don't know how to delete."  The question isn't for your deletion.  The purpose of Stack Exchange is to help everybody, not just one person, so questions and answers remain so that others can draw from them.

Comment: You cannot delete a question once an answer has been posted AND upvoted. Why would you? Accept Anton Sherwood's answer if he solved the question. Click on the grey checkmark that is underneath the down arrow. It turns bright green when you do, and the system awards you a bonus of two points.

Comment: What would EL&U (or any SE site) look like if everyone deleted their answer when someone answered it?

Answer (score 1):

The morphemes (in Latin) are *nō–* (earlier *gnō–*), which is a cognate of English *know*, and *–bil–*, which appears in many English words as *–ble* (usually after *a* or *i* of a verb stem).  The nobles are those whom most people ought to know.